# How do you wait for exactly two signals in C multiprocessing?

Tags: c, multiprocessing, signals, parent-child

In the main function I created a "**sigaction sigact**" which connects to a **handler**, and I removed the **SIGUSR1** signal from the blocked sigact.sa_mask set. **The SIGUSR1 is the signal I want to get twice** from TWO children before going further. How do I wait for both the children process to get the SIGUSR1 signals from?

```
void handler(...){...}

int main()
{
    int pipe1[2];
    int pipe2[2];
    
    char buf;

    struct sigaction sigact;
    sigact.sa_handler = handler;
    sigfillset(&sigact.sa_mask);
    sigact.sa_flags = 0;
    sigdelset(&sigact.sa_mask,SIGUSR1);
    sigaction(SIGUSR1,&sigact,NULL);

    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
       
       ...
       sleep(3);                                     // the sleep is just a must-have of the homework
       kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);                      // CHILD1
       ...                         

    }else{
          pid1 = fork();

          if(pid1 == 0){

                ...
                sleep(3);
                kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);             // CHILD2
                ...               
         
          }else{

               ...
               sigsuspend(&sigact.sa_mask);                    // PARENT
               sigsuspend(&sigact.sa_mask);                    // WAIT FOR SIGUSR1 FROM CHILD1 AND
               ...                                             // CHILD2 BEFORE GOING FURTHER
               ...                                             // (The two sigsuspends were my best idea, 
               ...                                             //  doesn't work)
               // DO OTHER THINGS AFTER TWO SIGNALS CAME 
               // (e.g. sending children data with pipes, 
               // just homework stuff...)

          }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As You can see I'm trying with two sigsuspends but they won't work, it waits forever. It would work by using only one sigsuspend but I need feedback from both children.

**How do you wait for 2 signals?**

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this. Consider using pipes to receive from the children.

Comment: I just can't because that's the homework at the university xD but thanks @Joshua

Comment: To allow SIGUSR1 to interrupt an already running SIGUSR1 handler, you must clear SIGUSR1 from the handler's `sa.sa_mask` (as you've done) _and_ also [set the `SA_NODEFER` flag](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html#tag_16_540_03).

Comment: As the [Linux man pages notes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html#NOTES), `sigsuspend` is normally used in conjunction with `sigprocmask` to temporarily unmask otherwise blocked signals.  Imagine that you did not have the `sleep(3)` in the children, but still wanted the parent to be interrupted _only_ in a call to `sigsuspend`.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done reliably with the constraints you have.  Push back on this homework.

If two SIGUSR1 signals arrive "at the same time," one will be lost, because [ordinary UNIX signals of the same type do not queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285647/132382).  You do not control this timing — the OS scheduler does.

So, do something else.  Use realtime signals which can [queue at least 32 (_POSIX_SIGQUEUE_MAX) pending signals](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html).  Use pipes between children and parent to communicate.  Use different ordinary signals (e.g., SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2) per process.  Etc.